# Requested device not found chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia, desktop-sharing

I am trying to create a web application which can share the desktop with the system audio using webrtc from chrome browser and if I set the constraints :

```
const constraints = {
audio: {
mandatory: {
  chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'
}
 },
video: {
mandatory: {
  chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'
}
}
 }
```

I get this error **"DOMException: Requested device not found" or "DOMException: Invalid state"**

here is the demo: https://codepen.io/EbramTawfik/pen/xQozaE

Comment: In Chrome, this can currently only be achieved from `chrome://` scripts (i.e extensions)

Comment: You need chrome extensions for screen sharing. Check this repo for examples: https://github.com/muaz-khan/Chrome-Extensions